# Strange results when applying a filter after using limit on a dataset in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 2.2.1 but my issue seems to happen as well in 2.4. I am trying to use the `limit` function whose definition is quoted below.

> ```
> def limit(n: Int): Dataset[T]
> Returns a new Dataset by taking the first n rows.
> ```

Here is a toy example that reproduces my problem.

```scala
scala> spark.range(10).limit(5).show()
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
+---+

scala> spark.range(10).limit(5).where('id > 3).show()
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  5|
|  6|
+---+
```

I would have expected a dataframe with only one row, containing `4`. Is it a bug, is it a feature? Anyway, I do not understand the result. Any hint towards an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataset is not inherently ordered, hence `limit(5)` could return `[0 1 2 3 4]` or `[1 3 5 7 9]`, `[2 7 1 3 8]`, etc. Applying an `orderBy` clause will give you the result you were expecting.

```
scala> spark.range(10).orderBy('id).limit(5).where('id > 3).show()
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  4|
+---+
```